# Found a character on a texture and need help identifying it

Tags: hangul

I noticed on a texture I found there was this (what I presume is a) Korean character.
For a while, this was what I was looking for:

[image]

I managed to find a better picture:

[image]

Although still not super clear. I did find this but to me it looks like a totally different character:

[image]

Either way, from what I figured out, the character I think is made up of `ㄹ`, `ㅇ`, `ㅣ`  (at least in the first two images) however I don't know how these "go together" to make the character. I have looked at the Wikipedia which shows how characters will be ordered and so on and I just haven't been able to figure it out.

Would anyone mind shedding some light on this character?

Comment: Try rotating it 180°

Comment: That is 일. If it is the only character there, it means one, work, day, the sun, etc.

Comment: The first and seconds ones are correct (일), just upside down. The third one sort of looks like a combination of Korean characters but is not an actual character.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply it wasn't showing I had any comments. Would there be any reason for it being rotated 180°?

Comment: Is it wallpaper or something else? Are there any other characters following 일?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/A1cpdiy - here's the full image. It's a texture of a gun from Halo 3. It has 문 *before* it.

Comment: So, it has 곱 (not 곰) after 일. The whole word is 일곱, which means seven. It is not normal to engrave a word rotated 180 degrees on a gun unless it is intended or done by mistake. I guess the artists did not know Korean well.

Comment: Fair enough. I will make sure make sure I correct it on my model. Thank you!

Comment: Note that ㅁ and upside down ㅂ aren't identical in any font, and ㄱ and ㄴ aren't equivalent in some fonts and contexts.

Answer (score 1):

일 would be the character that is upside down. However, I don't know if that word is the right word because the photo on the bottom looks a bit different than the second photo. It may be a Chinese character but the first and second photo is definitely 일 upside down which means work or day